# Wildcard search not working Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to find partial search matches using the LIKE keyword on my Eloquent model.

However, it isn't retrieving the LIKE value - only exact matches.

```
$insurancePolicy = InsurancePolicy::where( 'policy_number', 'LIKE', '%' . $policyNumber . '%' )->get();
```

I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `policy_number` sounds like a numeric field

Comment: It isn't - it is a string.

Comment: Try dumping the Sql so you can see what the actual query is. It may offer some insight. Swap `->get()` for `->toSql()` and print `$insurancePolicy`. You'll get ?'s for any parameters so it might be worthwhile printing `$policyNumber` at the same time so you can manually run the query.

Comment: Probably sensitive info to share, but what is `$policyNumber`? Are there `policy_number` values that are a partial match to it? Basically, and this may sound stupid, but ensure that there is actually data in your database that is a partial match to your `$policyNumber`

Comment: This is what it produces: 
`select * from insurance_policies where policy_number LIKE ?`

Then manually running the query:

`select * from insurance_policies where policy_number LIKE '%42-CF-K785-2%'`

Searching for `42-CF-K785-2` finds the result but anything else returns nothing.

Comment: Try running it in phpmyadmin or whatever front end you have. It'll either give you a result, give you nothing or error.

Comment: I am trying to match, say, 42-CF-K785-2 to 42CFK7852; but maybe that isn't possible since it is picking up the hyphens.

Comment: I am trying to query so that `42-CF-K785-2` and `42CFK7852` find the same thing; or, `42-CF` and `42CF` find the same thing.

Comment: Yeah, that's not quite how `LIKE` works in MySQL; `42CF` and `42-CF` will not match in a `LIKE` search. You'd have to do a MySQL `REPLACE()` function on your column, so something like `->whereRaw("REPLACE(policy_number, '-', '') LIKE '%".$policyNumber."%');`

Comment: Yes, this seems to work.. Thanks!

`SELECT * FROM insurance_policies WHERE (
 replace( policy_number, '-', '' ) LIKE '%42CFK7852%'
 OR policy_number LIKE '%42-CF-K785-2%'
)`

Comment: Nice; as long as you did the same replace (via PHP) for `$policyNumber`, that would work for you without issue. Just be aware that `LIKE` queries can be slow, so be aware of performance.